# How do I optimize this XML parsing loop for speed?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, beautifulsoup, nested-loops

I wrote a piece of code which parses through around a hundred XML files and creates a single dataframe. The code works fine but can take a pretty long time, a little less than an hour to run. I'm sure there is a way to improve this loop by only using dataframe objects at the end of the loop, or maybe you don't need the triple-nested loop to parse all the info into the dataframe,  but this is the only way I was able to do it as a novice.

My code looks like this :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import lxml
import json
import os

os.chdir(r"path_to_output_file/output_file")
f_list = os.listdir()

df_list = []

output_files = []
# checking we only iterate over XML files containing "calc_output"
for calc_output in f_list:
    if "calc_output" in calc_output and calc_output.endswith(".xml"):
        output_files.append(calc_output)
        
for calc_output in output_files:
    with open(calc_output, "r") as datas:
        print(f"reading file {calc_output} ...")

        doc = BeautifulSoup(datas.read(), "lxml")

        rows = []
        timestamps = doc.time.find_all("timestamp")
        for timestamp in timestamps: # parsing through every timestamp element
            row= {}
            time = timestamp.get("time") # reading timestamp attributes
            temperature = timestamp.get("temperature")
            zone_id = doc.zone.get("zone_id")
            time_id = timestamp.get("time_id")
            row.update({"time":time, "temperature":temperature, "time_id":time_id, "zone_id":zone_id})
            row_copy = row.copy()
            rows.append(row_copy)

        # creating temporary dataframe to combine with other info
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows)

        rows= []
        surfacedatas = doc.surfacehistory.find_all("surfacedata")
        for surfacedata in surfacedatas:
            row= {}
            #parsing through every surfacedata element
            time_begin = surfacedata.get("time-begin")
            time_end = surfacedata.get("time-end")
            row={"time-begin":time_begin, "time-end":time_end}

            things = surfacedata.find_all("thing", recursive=False)
            #parsing through every thing in each surfacedata
            for thing in things:
                identity = id2name(thing.get("identity"))
                row.update({"identity":identity})

                locations = thing.find_all("loc ation", recursive=False)
                for location in locations:
                    #parsing through every location for every thing for each surfacedata
                    l_identity = location.get("l_identity")
                    surface = location.getText()
                    row.update({"l_identity":l_identity, "surface":surface})
                    row_copy = row.copy()
                    rows.append(row_copy)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(rows) # second dataframe containing the information needed

    #merging each dataframe on every loop
    df =pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on="time_id", right_on="time-begin") 
    # then appending it to a list
    df_list.append(df)

# final dataframe created by concatenating each dataframe from each output file
df = pd.concat(df_list)
df
```

An example of an XML file would be :

**file 1**

```xml
<file filename="stack_example_1" created="today">
    <unit time="day" volume="cm3" surface="cm2"/>
    <zone zone_id="10">
        <time>
            <timestamp time_id="1" time="0" temperature="100"/>
            <timestamp time_id="2" time="10.00" temperature="200"/>
        </time>
        <surfacehistory type="calculation">
            <surfacedata time-begin="1" time-end="2">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l_identity="2"> 1.256</location>
                    <location l_identity="45"> 2.3</location>
                </thing>
                <thing identity="3">
                    <location l_identity="2"> 1.6</location>
                    <location l_identity="5"> 2.5</location> 
                    <location l_identity="78"> 3.2</location>
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
            <surfacedata time-begin="2" time-end="3">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l_identity="17"> 2.4</location>
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
        </surfacehistory>
    </zone>
</file>
```

**file 2**

```xml
<file filename="stack_example_2" created="today">
    <unit time="day" volume="cm3" surface="cm2"/>
    <zone zone_id="11">
        <time>
            <timestamp time_id="1" time="0" temperature="100"/>
            <timestamp time_id="2" time="10.00" temperature="200"/>
        </time>
        <surfacehistory type="calculation">
            <surfacedata time-begin="1" time-end="2">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.6</location>
                    <location l-identity="45"> 2.6</location>
                </thing>
                <thing identity="3">
                    <location l-identity="2"> 1.4</location>
                    <location l-identity="8"> 2.7</location>  
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
            <surfacedata time-begin="2" time-end="3">
                <thing identity="1">
                    <location l-identity="9"> 2.8</location>
                    <location l-identity="17"> 1.2</location>
                </thing>
            </surfacedata>
        </surfacehistory>
    </zone>
</file>
```

The output of this code using **file 1** and **file 2** would be :

```
zone_id     time       time_id  temperature tid-begin   tid-end    identity  location   surface
10           0          1       100         1           2          1        2           1,256
10           0          1       100         1           2          1        2           2,3
10           0          1       100         1           2          3        2           1,6
10           0          1       100         1           2          3        5           2,5
10           0          1       100         1           2          3        78          3,2
10           10         2       200         2           3          1        17          2,4
11           0          1       100         1           2          1        2           1,6
11           0          1       100         1           2          1        45          2,6
11           0          1       100         1           2          3        2           1,4
11           0          1       100         1           2          3        8           2,7
11           10         2       200         2           3          1        9           2,8
11           10         2       200         2           3          1        17          1,2
```

Here is the output obtained after running cProfile :

```
      Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 6281 to 20 due to restriction <20>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   214204   95.337    0.000   95.340    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py:343(raw_decode)
   214389   20.685    0.000   21.386    0.000 {built-in method io.open}
   214288   17.945    0.000   17.945    0.000 {built-in method _codecs.charmap_decode}
        1   16.745   16.745  336.360  336.360 .\anon_programm.py:7(<module>)
       10   15.378    1.538  132.814   13.281 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py:330(feed)
 10277616   12.975    0.000   44.266    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:555(endData)
   214228   12.504    0.000   30.575    0.000 {method 'read' of '_io.TextIOWrapper' objects}
  3425862   11.257    0.000   75.608    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py:223(start)
  6851244   10.806    0.000   19.427    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:589(object_was_parsed)
 17128360    8.580    0.000    8.580    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py:158(setup)
  3425862    8.389    0.000    8.694    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:527(popTag)
  5961888    7.170    0.000    7.170    0.000 {method 'keys' of 'dict' objects}
  3425872    7.072    0.000   23.054    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py:1152(__init__)
   214200    5.978    0.000  146.468    0.001 .\anon_programm.py:18(id2name)
  3425862    5.913    0.000   61.118    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:691(handle_starttag)
  3425002    4.482    0.000   12.571    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py:285(_replace_cdata_list_attribute_values)
  3425862    4.326    0.000   37.251    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_lxml.py:278(end)
  3425862    4.244    0.000   13.552    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:657(_popToTag)
  2751774    4.240    0.000    6.154    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py:808(<genexpr>)
  6851244    3.869    0.000    8.629    0.000 C:\Users\anon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py:932(__new__)
```

Here is the function that is called a lot in the loop :

```py
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
def id2name(id):
    name_Dict = json.loads( open(r"path_to_JSON_file\file.json","r").read() )
    name = ""
    if id.isnumeric():
        partial_id = id[:-1]  
        if partial_id not in name_Dict.keys():
            return id
        if id[-1] == "0":
            return  name_Dict[partial_id]
        else:
            return  name_Dict[partial_id]+"x"+id[-1]
    else:
        return ""
```

Comment: If the files are valid XML, then you'd want to use an XML library, not `BeautifulSoup`, which takes its own sweet time to try to fix invalid markup.

Comment: Your suggestion is valid a I could use the lxml library directly for example. However I wanted to see if I could make my code good engough without having to rewrite the program.

Comment: Well - have you used a profiler to see where your program is taking the most time?

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear. I meant to say without whanging the library I'm currently using unless it's abolutely necessary.

Comment: @AKX I am currently running cProfile on my programm. I will post the results as soon as I get them. As I said before, using lxml directly will surely improve the speed, I just wanted to be sure nothing could be done about the triple-nested loop in my code before that.

Comment: @Bobbert For your own patience and sanity, run the profiler on a subset of your files :) `output_files = output_files[:50]`, for instance...

Comment: Guess I should've figured that one out haha...

Comment: @AKX I added the cProfile output for the program in the main post.

Comment: Well, based on that output, the majority of time is being spent in BS4 and decoding JSON (and you're not showing us any code that uses `json`...)

Comment: (Also, next time you might want to show more cProfile rows, as well as sort it by `tottime` as well, not just `cumtime`, since `cumtime` contains time spent in functions called by that function...)

Comment: yeah, I'm using a simple function who translates the ```identity``` tag of the ```thing ```element to an actual name which I left out of the example to try and make it more simple. I guess I'll just follow your advice and use an XML library, thanks for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243191/discussion-between-bobbert-and-akx).

Comment: As an aside: your example data files don't work with your code: `KeyError: 'time-begin'` when merging the DFs. (EDIT: that's because there's a `loc ation` typo.)

Comment: Also: why would you need `json` for the identity tags? They seem to be just numbers.

Comment: the `identity` tags can be translated into a name by using a json library. I hope this makes it clearer

Comment: Well – in case the identity tags have a lot of repetition over the files, you could wrap that parsing function in `@functools.lru_cache` for a likely easy win, so it only does the parsing work once for a given input.

Comment: I will try and do that, certainly seems like the main contributor. I edited the post to sort by tottime and expanded the list to 20 rows.

Comment: @Bobbert It's certainly weird that your program is calling `io.open()` to open files a total of 214389 times if you only have about 100 XML files...

Comment: ah yeah, this is because the function opens the JSON file at the beginning and then closes it. I thought about that and decided to change it in order for it to only open once

Comment: At the beginning of what..? What is in the JSON file..? Could you read the JSON file into memory only once, at the start of your program, instead of parsing it over and over again?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I added the function used to my question. I meant just as you said and realized that the json file only had to be called once instead the number of loops. I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: I was also about to recommend just loading the JSON file once. At the moment, the result of the JSON file lookup is cached, but the JSON file itself is not cached, so you are loading it from disk and then parsing it every time you look up a name. Instead, you should cache the entire parsed JSON object in memory when you load it from disk the first time. (Or just load it once at the start of your program.)

Comment: Yeah... beyond the fact that you should move the JSON loading to a separately cached function (or load the file only once into a global) as @JackTaylor said, you should also take a good hard look at how that function is structured: you load a big JSON file, then _after it_ see if the id is non-numeric and return an empty string. One of my rules of thumb is to handle exceptional cases early, so `if not id.isnumeric(): return ''` at the start of the function would already save you a bunch of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments on your question, a large chunk of the time is being spent decoding JSON in your id2name function. While the results of the function are cached, the parsed JSON object is not, which means you are loading the JSON file from disk and parsing it each time you look up a new ID.

Assuming that you are loading the same JSON file each time, this means you should get an immediate speed-up by caching the parsed JSON object. You can do that by restructuring your id2name function as follows.

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache()
def load_name_dict():
    with open(r"path_to_JSON_file\file.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f: 
        return json.load(f)

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=1000)
def id2name(thing_id):
    if not thing_id.isnumeric():
        return ""
    name_dict = load_name_dict()
    name = name_dict.get(thing_id[:-1])
    if name is None:
        return thing_id
    last_char = thing_id[-1]
    if last_char == "0":
        return name
    else:
        return name + "x" + last_char
```

Note that I have refactored the id2name function to not load the JSON object if the ID is non-numeric. I've also changed it to use the `.get` method instead of `in` to avoid an unnecessary dictionary lookup. In addition, I changed `id` to `thing_id`, as [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) is a built-in function in Python.

Also, as your input files seem to be valid XML, you could likely save more time by using lxml directly instead of going through BeautifulSoup. Or probably even better, you can load the XML directly into a dataframe using [pandas.read_xml](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html#pandas-read-xml). A caveat, though; you should profile the resulting code to check that it actually runs faster, instead of taking my word for it. Intuitions about performance are notoriously unreliable; you should always measure it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**pandas.read_xml**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html#pandas-read-xml) that can run XSLT 1.0 using the default `lxml` parser to flatten your XML:

**XSLT** *(save below as .xsl script, a special .xml file)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::location"/>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="location">
    <xsl:variable name="s_pos" select="count(ancestor::surfacedata/preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
    <row>
      <zone_id>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::zone/@zone_id"/>
      </zone_id>
      <time>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::zone/time/timestamp[position()=$s_pos]/@time"/>
      </time>
      <time_id>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::zone/time/timestamp[position()=$s_pos]/@time_id"/>
      </time_id>
      <temperature>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::zone/time/timestamp[position()=$s_pos]/@temperature"/>
      </temperature>
      <t_begin>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::surfacedata/@time-begin"/>
      </t_begin>
      <t_end>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::surfacedata/@time-end"/>
      </t_end>
      <identity>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::thing/@identity"/>
      </identity>
      <location>
        <xsl:value-of select="@l_identity"/>
      </location>
      <surface>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </surface>
    </row>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet+xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22+version%3D%221.0%22%3E%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Aoutput+method%3D%22xml%22+indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cdata%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates+select%3D%22descendant%3A%3Alocation%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2Fdata%3E%0D%0A++%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A++%0D%0A++%3Cxsl%3Atemplate+match%3D%22location%22%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cxsl%3Avariable+name%3D%22s_pos%22+select%3D%22count%28ancestor%3A%3Asurfacedata%2Fpreceding-sibling%3A%3A*%29+%2B+1%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++%3Crow%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Czone_id%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22ancestor%3A%3Azone%2F%40zone_id%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Fzone_id%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Ctime%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22ancestor%3A%3Azone%2Ftime%2Ftimestamp%5Bposition%28%29%3D%24s_pos%5D%2F%40time%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Ftime%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Ctime_id%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22ancestor%3A%3Azone%2Ftime%2Ftimestamp%5Bposition%28%29%3D%24s_pos%5D%2F%40time_id%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Ftime_id%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Ctemperature%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22ancestor%3A%3Azone%2Ftime%2Ftimestamp%5Bposition%28%29%3D%24s_pos%5D%2F%40temperature%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Ftemperature%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Ct_begin%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22ancestor%3A%3Asurfacedata%2F%40time-begin%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Ft_begin%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Ct_end%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22ancestor%3A%3Asurfacedata%2F%40time-end%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Ft_end%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Cidentity%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22ancestor%3A%3Athing%2F%40identity%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Fidentity%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Clocation%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22%40l_identity%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Flocation%3E%0D%0A++++++%3Csurface%3E%0D%0A++++++++%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of+select%3D%22text%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A++++++%3C%2Fsurface%3E%0D%0A++++%3C%2Frow%3E%0D%0A++%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A++%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Cfile+filename%3D%22stack_example_1%22+created%3D%22today%22%3E%0A++++%3Cunit+time%3D%22day%22+volume%3D%22cm3%22+surface%3D%22cm2%22%2F%3E%0A++++%3Czone+zone_id%3D%2210%22%3E%0A++++++++%3Ctime%3E%0A++++++++++++%3Ctimestamp+time_id%3D%221%22+time%3D%220%22+temperature%3D%22100%22%2F%3E%0A++++++++++++%3Ctimestamp+time_id%3D%222%22+time%3D%2210.00%22+temperature%3D%22200%22%2F%3E%0A++++++++%3C%2Ftime%3E%0A++++++++%3Csurfacehistory+type%3D%22calculation%22%3E%0A++++++++++++%3Csurfacedata+time-begin%3D%221%22+time-end%3D%222%22%3E%0A++++++++++++++++%3Cthing+identity%3D%221%22%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Clocation+l_identity%3D%222%22%3E+1.256%3C%2Flocation%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Clocation+l_identity%3D%2245%22%3E+2.3%3C%2Flocation%3E%0A++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fthing%3E%0A++++++++++++++++%3Cthing+identity%3D%223%22%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Clocation+l_identity%3D%222%22%3E+1.6%3C%2Flocation%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Clocation+l_identity%3D%225%22%3E+2.5%3C%2Flocation%3E+%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Clocation+l_identity%3D%2278%22%3E+3.2%3C%2Flocation%3E%0A++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fthing%3E%0A++++++++++++%3C%2Fsurfacedata%3E%0A++++++++++++%3Csurfacedata+time-begin%3D%222%22+time-end%3D%223%22%3E%0A++++++++++++++++%3Cthing+identity%3D%221%22%3E%0A++++++++++++++++++++%3Clocation+l_identity%3D%2217%22%3E+2.4%3C%2Flocation%3E%0A++++++++++++++++%3C%2Fthing%3E%0A++++++++++++%3C%2Fsurfacedata%3E%0A++++++++%3C%2Fsurfacehistory%3E%0A++++%3C%2Fzone%3E%0A%3C%2Ffile%3E&input-type=XML)</kbd>

**Python** *(simple list comprehension without multiple nesting and merging)*

```py
df_list = [
    pd.read_xml(calc_output, stylesheet="flatten.xsl")
    for calc_output in output_files
]

surface_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

You can then run your `id2name()` (loading JSON beforehand and not with each function call) directly on the *identity* data frame column with `Series.apply`:

```py
surface_df["id_name"] = surface_df["identity"].apply(id2name)
```